# Linux Scripting to arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

suppose I have a script file "display.sh" which displays some output.

```
Name -Xander  
Age-29       //   Step 1
```

I want to add something extra to this output.

```
Name -Xander
Age-29
occupation-Cricketer //extra stuff
```

Now when I give command display.sh, only Step 1 should display
But when I give command (display.sh -t or -f or anything) both step 1 and extra stuff should display

How this last part can be achieved??

Comment: What is the source of `step 1` or `step 2` information. Add sample data and your effort so far.

Comment: have a look at `getopt` or `getopts` to handle script options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full-blown solution, use `getopt` or `getopts` as suggested by Aserre.

However, imho this is often overkill. If you have only one or two flags without arguments, a simple `if`-`then` might be sufficient.

You will need to look into how to use command line arguments in bash

To help you with an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "-f" ] ; then
    do_the_rest=1
else
    do_the_rest=0
fi
# lots of code for your display script
if [ $do_the_rest = 1 ] ; then
    # code to display the rest of the lines
fi
```